# Что такое CDN Base URL в плагине Autoptimize?

Tags: php, wordpress

В плагине Autoptimize есть опция CDN Base URL, направленная, как знаю, на западных посетителей. Что это за опция?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не только на западных посетителей. Если сайт кешируется и раздается через систему доставки контента CDN, то эта опция указывает, где разместить файлы плагина Autoptimize.
В России есть свои сети сети CDN: NGENIX, CDN77 и другие.

Настройка этой опции зависит от выбранного провайдера CDN.

Comment: Скажите, выходит, туда просто кладутся файлы как на файлообменник по заданным ссылкам и лишь имя отличается, по которому потом и доступен файл?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov зависит от провайдера, зачастую ссылка на файл через cdn может выглядеть как `http://вашсайт.ru/имя_вашего_файла`

Comment: @Alex, большое спасибо за комментарий!

Comment: @TimurMusharapov а где у ngenix цены на cdn?

Comment: Не знаю, у меня заказчик связан с CDN, вот решил уточнить, что это :)

Comment: @TimurMusharapov базовая ссылка имеет примерно такой вид: https://maxcdn.ваш-сайт.ru и информирует плагин, где находятся файлы.

Все файлы на cdn попадают автоматически, ничего туда класть не надо.